# PHP Form IF Issues

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have this in the top part of my code

```
    require(__DIR__ . "/lib/db.php");
if (!empty($_POST["action"])) {
        if ($_POST["action"] == "addCat") {
            echo "Please wait...";
            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."')";
            if (mysql_query($sql1)) {
                $success = true;
            }
            if (!isset($success)) {
                echo "Error Occured Adding Category!";
            } else {
                echo "Category added!";
            }
        }
        if ($_POST["action"] == "delCat") {
            echo "Please wait...";
            $catNames = $_POST['catName'];
            if(empty($catNames)) {
                return;
            } else {
                $N = count($catNames);
                for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE id='$catNames[$i]'";
                    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
                        $success = true;
                    }
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM catrel WHERE categoryID = '$catNames[$i]'";
                    if (mysql_query($sql2)) {
                        mysql_query("DELETE FROM catrel WHERE categoryID = '$catNames[$i]'");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isset($success)) {
                echo "Could not delete category! Error Occured!";
            } else {
                echo "Category deleted!";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a 2 different forms in the same page, with hidden values that will push addCat or delCat. For some reason it seems like the SQL is not getting parsed, however it is not displaying any errors. Any help would be highly appreciated. I can post the entire page if needed.

Comment: Try adding `print_r($_POST)` to the beginning to see what you are actually getting from the form. Please remember also to sanitize what you're putting in your SQL, since a malicious user might be able to inject whatever data in your form.

Comment: Do you get any output at all? Try using `mysql_error()` to know if a query failed

Comment: And there's also a `foreach($N as $n)` loop in PHP instead a  `for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)`loop :)

Comment: I tried the print_r, and I am not getting anything. No SQL error either when adding the mysql_error()

Comment: I can post the entire page up somewhere if someone could give it a glance.

Comment: @Nicron if `print_r($_POST)` is empty, your form is not sending the results to your PHP file. The `<form>` tag `action` parameter should reference your PHP script.